# Bookmark skips section and only displays subsection

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks

I've used such a command to generate bookmarks,

`\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}`

However, only subsections appear in the bookmarks. Did I miss something?

I'm using `ascelike-new` document class which is specifically for Journal of Enginnerging Mechanics. The MWE is provided herein,

```
\documentclass[Journal,letterpaper]{ascelike-new}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \section{Introduction}
 \subsection{Exp1}
 \subsection{Exp2}
 \section{Conclusions}
 \subsection{Exp3}
 \subsection{Exp4}
\end{document}
```

Best,

Comment: That's no a MWE, it is far from being minimal. Remove all the irrelevant packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Now I removed unnecessary packages.

Comment: Well remove also the \begin{equation} and then it will be perfect. But beside this: your example clearly shows that the class is at fault, it redefines \section in a way that breaks hyperref, so complain to the author.

Comment: Adding a link to the exact `documentclass` (and relevant files it possibly requires) should help us to have a look... (doesn't needed to add all this code... but at least a link to the official-er -:P- page that this `documentclass` can be found could make your example a "working example")

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, many thanks, I believe so. I was thinking hyperref cannot be broken. I probably need to either check the class file or contact that author.

Comment: @koleygr, Hi, the link is posted here, but it requires registering. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-the-american-society-of-civil-engineers-asce/pbwcqsvndpty#.Vz8K-_lVhBc